# Macro naming conventions

Tags: macros, naming, latex-misc

Some documents define very short macro and environment names. E.g: problem, proof, and solution environments as `\begin{pr}, \begin{pf}, \begin{sol}`, or variables like `\parallel` redefined as `\pl`.

1. Is this considered a bad practice?
2. Is it problematic to have short convenient macros in terms of portability (e.g: publishing in journal), or can they be easily converted automatically?

Comment: Not authoritative comment: If the macro is for internal use within your own code, it is good to put a "namespace" prefix before anything you define. Also put an `@` in the macro, which signals that it should not appear visible in the document body. Example: `\def\yrs@mymacro{}`. Expl3 has other methods (unknown to me). If the macro is for direct usage in a document body, where the code is visible to anyone who looks at the `*.tex` file as plain tex, then use commands without the `@`. You may wish to use the namespace if the command name is used elsewhere.

Comment: It's neither bad nor good practice. The main problem I see is that something like `\pl` hinders readability of the source, particularly if you take again the document after some time and don't remember what `\pl` was about. I've seen document defining such abbreviations and also the unabbreviated command. Do you think to have a net gain with `\begin{pf}` instead of `\begin{proof}`? Then go along.